# Materialzed view works for few days and then stops

Tags: clickhouse

I have these three table (I cleaned them)

```
CREATE TABLE Record (
   `visitId` String,
   `visitorId` String,
   `pageUrl` LowCardinality(String),
   `createdAtDay` Date DEFAULT now()
) ENGINE = MergeTree PARTITION BY toYYYYMM(createdAtDay) PRIMARY KEY (
   visitorId,
   visitId,
   pageUrl,
   createdAtDay
)
ORDER BY
   (visitorId, visitId, pageUrl)
   
CREATE MATERIALIZED VIEW DurationPerPage (
   `visits` Int64 CODEC(DoubleDelta, LZ4),
   `pageUrl` LowCardinality(String),
   `visitors` Int64 CODEC(DoubleDelta, LZ4),
   `duration` Int64 CODEC(DoubleDelta, LZ4),
   `createdAtDay` Date,
) ENGINE = SummingMergeTree((visits, visitors, duration))
ORDER BY
   (createdAtDay, pageUrl) AS
SELECT
   countDistinct(visitId) AS visits,
   cutQueryStringAndFragment(pageUrl) AS pageUrl,
   countDistinct(visitorId) AS visitors,
   sum(e.value) AS duration,
   createdAtDay
FROM
   Record AS r
   LEFT JOIN Events AS e ON (r.visitId = e.visitId)
   AND (e.eventType = 6)
WHERE
   pageType LIKE '%single%'
GROUP BY
   (createdAtDay, pageUrl);

CREATE TABLE Events (
   `visitId` String,
   `visitorId` String,
   `value` Int64 CODEC(DoubleDelta, LZ4),
   `eventType` Int16 CODEC(DoubleDelta, LZ4)
) ENGINE = MergeTree PARTITION BY (toYYYYMM(createdAtDay), eventType) PRIMARY KEY (visitId, eventType, createdAtDay)
ORDER BY
   (visitId, eventType, createdAtDay)
```

as you can see I'm using both Record and Events table to feed my materialzed view. it works good for few days and then it stops and starts saving weird data (mostly zeros at the duration field) and I have then to delete and recreate it.

is there a related bug to this ? or something is wrong the View ?

Comment: I have more than 20 columns in each table. and in the MV I'm just collecting 6 columns. thanks for the link I'll take a look into that

Comment: countDistinct cannot be used in MatView. Because MatView is an insert trigger. countDistinct calculates mostly garbage. https://den-crane.github.io/Everything_you_should_know_about_materialized_views_commented.pdf

Comment: remove `( )` from group by (Clichouse handles `( )` incorrectly). Must be `GROUP BY createdAtDay, pageUrl`

Comment: `SummingMergeTree((visits, visitors, duration))` use this `SummingMergeTree()`. All columns which are not in the ORDERBY will be summed automatically.

Comment: @DennyCrane what do you suggest instead of coundeDistinct ? else, I will try the group by tip and I'll see if it works!